# Android ListView bug on first item using picasso

Tags: android, listview, adapter, picasso

Ι have a ListView adapter that loads basketball team games. I'm loading my images with picasso or resources if it's the team that the app is for. On my first item it seems to load both teams's images from the web. Here is a sample code and image.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
    }

    Match programItem = getItem(position);     
    ImageView ourTeamLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_our_team_logo);      
    ImageView foeLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_foe_logo);

    if (programItem.isHome()) {

        ourTeamLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);

        Picasso.with(context).
                cancelRequest(foeLogo);
        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
                .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(foeLogo);        
    }
    else {

        foeLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);

        Picasso.with(context).
                cancelRequest(ourTeamLogo);
        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
                .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(ourTeamLogo);
    }

    return view;
}
```

See first item marked in red:

[image]

Comment: what is your problem. Please explain more.

Comment: First element marked with red should not have the same image on both sides. If I scroll down and up it recycles the view correctly tho.

Comment: Did you implemented ViewHolder in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, seems like I needed to add

Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(holder.ourTeamLogo);
Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(holder.foeTeamLogo);

```
    static class ViewHolder {
ImageView ourTeamLogo, foeLogo;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.ourTeamLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_our_team_logo);
    holder.foeLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_foe_logo);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

Match programItem = getItem(position);

if (programItem.isHome()) {

    holder.ourTeamLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);

    Picasso.with(context).
                cancelRequest(holder.ourTeamLogo);
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
            .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(holder.foeLogo);
} else {

    holder.foeLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);
    Picasso.with(context).
                cancelRequest(holder.ourTeamLogo);
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
            .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(holder.ourTeamLogo);
}

return view;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

things I noticed that were wrong in your code

```
 Holder holder=null;
if(view==null)
{
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
    holder = new Holder(view, position);
    view.setTag(holder);
}
else{
     holder=(Holder)view.getTag();
    }
//Continue your code here
```

Comment: I ll give it a try and will be back to you.

Comment: Do I need to make a Holder Class?

Comment: Yes. keeping ViewHolder is a best practice. It will reuse the views that are inflated already. No need to inflate the same layout again.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement ViewHolder like this,

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ourTeamLogo, foeLogo;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ourTeamLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_our_team_logo);
        holder.foeLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.program_item_foe_logo);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Match programItem = getItem(position);

    if (programItem.isHome()) {

        holder.ourTeamLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);

        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
                .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(holder.foeLogo);
    } else {

        holder.foeLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.our_team_logo);

        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(programItem.getFoeLogoURL())
                .fit().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_team).into(holder.ourTeamLogo);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Issue still exists, scroll seems smother thought, you forgot view.setTag(holder); once added it worked like a charm.